# How to evaluate testing dataset by every epoch for tensorflow estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

For tf.estimator, it will run all epochs, and then do evaluation, but how to evaluate testing dataset by every epoch so that we can see a line in tensorboard instead of a single point

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a loop like following:

```
def input_fn(files):
  ds = dataset...
  return ds (without repeat)
for _ n_epochs:
  estimator.train(input_fn(train-files))
  estimator.evaluate(input_fn(eval-files))
```

Comment: It seems the session will be created and ended again and again.